# Java Desktop Application Installer on Mac and Windows and Linux

Tags: java, windows, macos, installation, desktop-application

I make a java application I want to make the setup file save in the USB. Firstly the installation process will check is JDK or JRE is installed or not and then proceed further installations.
Is there any tool or anything way please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a standalone installer with [Self-Contained Application Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).

According to the documentation you can create packaged application in one or more of the following deployment modes:

- As a standalone application, using the system
- As a self-contained application, using a private copy of JRE
- As a Java Web Start application, using the system JRE
- Embedded in a web page, using the system JRE

Comment: The Java Plug-In required for the last two options (JWS / embedded in web page) has been flagged for deprecation and has already been removed from most browsers.